# File sharing on specific server not working over WAN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing, wide-area-network

I have an internal only SharePoint server we're in the process of migrating off of. I have administrators of the server that up until recently were always able to use the UNC path to accomplish what they needed to.  This has stopped working for those admins who are remote to the server.

Using the UNC path I can browse the c$ share from PC's and servers at the same site, including over multiple VLANs.  So routing is working correctly, and file sharing seems to be working.  I can browse the C$ share of other servers from the remote site, so I don't think it's an overall network issue.  It seems to only be this one server, with but only with connections from the WAN.  I do have 2 other web front ends that I can browse with no problem.

DNS resolves correctly, ping and RDP do work just fine from both sites.  The IIS SharePoint site works fine as well.  The server is 2008R2 with SharePoint Foundation 2010.  No firewall is running on the server.  I have rebooted the server, and the clients we have tried to connect from.   I'm out of ideas and haven't found anything.  Thoughts?

Comment: I see talk about multiple site and VLAN, but I see WAN in your question, is those guys accessing the server from a public site, like the server is in a DMZ ? or do I misinterpret your question because of the word WAN in it

Comment: Is the default gateway set correctly on this server?

Comment: It was not a public network, just our internal network spread across an MPLS cloud.  Yes the gateways on all systems are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those trying to help.  We discovered that a caching device between sites was changing the SMB2 traffic to SMB1 which was disabled on the server.  That is why local traffic was fine, it was all using SMB2 correctly.